# Is there a commercial/open source C# wrapper component for using a webcam in Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, webcam, directshow, video-capture

I need to rapidly develop some software that uses a camera as an AV input.

Assuming the drivers are installed for whatever the device that is giving the input I need to be able to capture images and to stream the camera in the winforms window.

I couldn't find a component that I can use, maybe because I don't know the right name for it.

Touchless is under a licence I can't use. If anyone knows of a good compoment/code I can use even if it's for a fee I will appreciate this.

Answer (score 5):

DirectShow.NET library suits the bill here. You can use it to access the webcam directly using the underlaying DirectShow object as in here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/WebcamUsingDirectShowNET.aspx

Also if you consider learning WPF, there is a very neat webcam component here: http://wpfcap.codeplex.com/
It is just like dropping a image control on the worm, but this time in WPF:

Edit: There are also two Winform webcam components as I see now: http://easywebcam.codeplex.com/ and http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/810262008070218AM/8.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This [article](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Look-at-me-Windows-Image-Acquisition) explains how to access the webcam using Windows Image Aquisition services.

Comment: I am not am expert in this, does WIA covers all drivers for AV input. I need my software to work on any computer regardless of the AV adapter ( internal card,USB tracecoder,...)

Comment: I would not dare comment on that. WIA is the official route-- but often with video devices I have found that manufacturers have their own peculiar implementations. You should look around to see how wide spread WIA is.